# Django - what is wrong with my If statement?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I inserted an if statement in my template - I only want the form to appear if the product category is "Champagne".

For some reason, the product does not appear for champagne products.

Here is the code

**Models.py**

```
CATEGORY=(
    (1,'Rum'),
    (2,'Gin'),
    (3,'Whisky'),
    (4,'Champagne'),
    (5,'Others'),
    )

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Product Name', max_length=120, null=True)
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORY, default=0)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)
    image_url= models.URLField('Image Web Address', blank=True)
    product_url = models.URLField('Product Web Address', blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table='Product'
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

**HTML**

```
{% if product.category == 'Champagne' %}
<div class="d-flex flex-column mt-4">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" href="{% url 'ElderFlowerReview' product.id %}">Tasting Notes</a>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

**Forms.py**

```
class DrinkForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name','category', 'description')
        labels ={
            'name': '',
            'category': '',
            'description': '',
        }

        widgets = {
                    'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter name'}),
                    'category': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter category'}),
                    'description':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter description'}),
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use 4 insted of "Champagne"
4 is value and "Champagne" is label

**HTML**

```
{% if product.category == 4 %}
<div class="d-flex flex-column mt-4"> 
<a class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" href="{% url 'ElderFlowerReview' product.id %}">Tasting Notes</a> 
</div> 
{% endif %}
```